# Can a KQL query find pages with tags that match the current page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-column, kql

The problem I'm trying to solve is I have a content type "wiki page" that contains a custom site column called "features". I have a "issues" folder on my site filled with other "wiki pages" which also have the features column type.

I'm trying to build a content search app that displays any "wiki pages" from that folder that match the "features" of the current page that the content search web part resides on.

I can easily pull everything from the folder, I can even search for a particular feature, but does KQL allow me to pull from something currently on the page to find what I should even be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I Finally figured it out. I was doing two things wrong.

Anytime you're searching other pages for a site column, you're not searching for a column called "features" you need to search for a second column that was automatically created when you built your site column. (it will be listed under Schema in site settings, most likely it has a OWS appended to the name) That's what is actually being updated and crawled periodically. That's how I finally got multiple results to start appearing.
FeaturesOWSTXT:{page.Features}

My second problem was that choice Columns were a terrible way of doing what I was trying to do. It works great when there is only one result for Page.Features but the moment you get two or more a choice column will return feature1;#feature2;#feature3;# (etc.) wherever page.Features is. KQL does not like that (although I don't know why they bothered making it return like that then). It kind of defeats the purpose of a multiple choice column.

I ended up switching from a Multiple Choice column to a managed meta data column and using it as a multiple choice column. Then the only thing I had to write was
{?{|owstaxIdProductFeatures:{page.ProductFeatures}}} and voila.

Moral of the story... just stick with managed meta data. A multiple Choice column just... It just pales in comparison compared to what you can do with the term store.

http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/sharepoint-search-queries-explained.html